# How to use xslt 1.0 translate() to replace multiple characters when one of the desired characters would be blank

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

I am wondering the most efficient way to perform the following xslt variable selection:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(translate('1aaa1a1paa6a5p5aa4paaa52', 'a', ''), 'p' , '.')" />
```

The output should end up being `111.65.54.52`

With this code it is correct, I am just wondering if there is a way to combine the two translate functions!

Thanks

Comment: `translate('1aaa1a1paa6a5p5aa4paaa52','pa','.')`

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks